# javascript div displaying incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I don't work with JavaScript very often. Work more on the back end. Please be gentle.

Background:

I have been tasked with visualising an address database on a map.

So, I've gone with google maps.

Built a KML and a page and it looks really good.

But, I am having problems getting the streetview map to appear in the correct pop on it.

Visually, I can explain the problem. zoom in a few times then click a few pins/icons.

It should open a window. click another pin and the original window should disappear and new one with the correct streetview should appear in it.

At the moment. the first window opens empty. then when you click the second icon, a new empty window appears the map appears in the first windows.

Technically, I don't know how to explain the problem. It feels like I need to somehow make that  invisible or destroy it.

this is what I am seeing...

[image: this is what I am seeing]

This is the site im working on. http://googlemap.azurewebsites.net/

and this is the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Street View service</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {

        var cardiff = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var mapOptions = {
            center: cardiff,
            zoom: 14
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://googlemap.azurewebsites.net/data6.txt',
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<div id='pano' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'></div><div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.name + "</div>" + "<div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.description + "</div>"
            });


            var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': kmlEvent.featureData.description }, function (results, status)
            {
                var address = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.ob, results[0].geometry.location.pb);
                var panoramaOptions = {
                    position: address,
                    pov: {
                        heading: 34,
                        pitch: 10
                    }
                };

                //obj = document.getElementById("pano");
                //document.body.removeChild(obj);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: address,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
                });

                var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                map.setStreetView(panorama);

            });

        });


    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  <div id="pano"></div>
<!--<div id="pano" style="position:absolute; left:410px; top: 8px; width: 400px; height:     300px;"></div>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Trev

Comment: Not sure but seems to me you have one <div id="pano"></div> in your html and then onclick adding another inside javascript code **content: "<div id='pano' style='wi...**, might be multiple elements with same id?

Comment: that's what im thinking too.

Comment: I will suggest you to use [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a timing problem.

1. click on marker
2. create marker and infowindow
3. open infowindow
4. attempt to open streetview, there is no id='pano' div in the DOM (the infowindow isn't rendered yet)
5. click another marker
6. create marker and infowindow
7. open infowindow
8. open streetview, there is now a div with id='pano' (in the infowindow on the last marker).

Two things:

1. only use one global infowindow
2. use the 'domready' event on the infowindow to render the streetview.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_KmlLayer_StreetviewA.html)

```
    <script>
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    function initialize() {

        var cardiff = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var mapOptions = {
            center: cardiff,
            zoom: 14
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://googlemap.azurewebsites.net/data6.txt',
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {
            infowindow.setContent("<div id='pano' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'></div><div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.name + "</div>" + "<div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.description + "</div>");

            var address = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status)
            {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                var panoramaOptions = {
                    position: latlng,
                    pov: {
                        heading: 34,
                        pitch: 10
                    }
                };

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: address
                });
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
                  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
                  map.setStreetView(panorama);
                });

            });

        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating infowindows inside the click handler, so you are creating a new infowindow with every click, you should just create **one** infowindow, and in your click handler just update its contents.

I updated your code to use just one infowindow, try it:

```
function initialize() {

    var cardiff = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var mapOptions = {
        center: cardiff,
        zoom: 14
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://googlemap.azurewebsites.net/data6.txt',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {

        infowindow.setContent("<div id='pano' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'></div><div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.name + "</div>" + "<div>" + kmlEvent.featureData.description + "</div>");


        var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': kmlEvent.featureData.description }, function (results, status)
        {
            var address = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.ob, results[0].geometry.location.pb);
            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: address,
                pov: {
                    heading: 34,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            };

            //obj = document.getElementById("pano");
            //document.body.removeChild(obj);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: address,
                map: map,
                title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
            });

            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

            map.setStreetView(panorama);

        });

    });


}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  infoWindow.close();
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Perhaps we should not also forget, that `google.maps` actually is executed asynchronously?

Comment: my friend on twitter has also pointed out that he thinks I might be suffering from this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588293/streetview-into-infowindow

Comment: @Nelson thanks for the time you took to look at this. Much appreciated!